# Save Project History

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

What is the best way to maintain the Version of entire solution and saving their details.

All changes made to the project are saved as a new version, so you can recover old versions at any time.

Members of your team, for example,
Can see the latest version of any file, make additional changes and then save another newer
version.

If these changes are later not accepted the version could be deleted and you can revert to the previous version.

Currently, I manually copy and past the entire folder in windows explorer and rename the folder manually.

Comment: Sounds like you should read up on source code management systems like Subversion or Git.

Comment: This is known as Version Control, or Source Control.  There are many different systems available, some open source, some proprietary (some of those have free tiers etc).  One popular system is [git](http://git-scm.com/).  The Microsoft solution is [Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/vstudio/ff637362.aspx).  Personally I use [Plastic SCM](http://www.plasticscm.com/home.html) at the moment.

Comment: Which one of this is GUI based?

Comment: I can't speak for the others, but Plastic has a good UI.  It's free for under 15 users per server.  No affiliation other than being a satisfied user...

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are version control systems. Notable systems are Subversion (SVN), git or the Microsoft Team Foundation Server if you want to stay within their line of products.

Comment: Yes. I also shortlisted on this 3 system. Will start using GIT and let see how it works. Which is the preferred industry standard?

Comment: This depends. In my oppinion Git seems to be the dominant tool in open source software development. As many companies which develop on Visual Studio want to stay within Microsoft's product family, the Team Foundation Server is quite common in the professional sector. I suggest you have a look at those 3 tools and decide which one to use depending on your work style / collaboration.